# How to display only date in KendoDateTime picker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I've placed a `kendo DateTime Picker` on a `web page`.

According to the requirement initially it should display only date and if user needs then he/she can select the time as well.

Below is the `code` which initially fill the `kendo datetime picker`:

```
 <input id="txtDate" type="text" maxlength="10" style="width: 250px;" value="" />

  <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#txtDate').kendoDateTimePicker({ value: new Date() });
</script>
```

The above code fill date and time. But i want to fill only current date.

I tried with the following code to check if it can fill only date. But it adds the 12:00 AM with date.

```
 $('#txtDate').kendoDateTimePicker({ value: new Date('04/30/2017') });
```

[image: kendo datetime picker image]

Is there any way to fill only `date` in `Kendo DateTime picker`?

Comment: Have you tried to set the format? http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/datetimepicker/overview

Comment: @GiovanniRomio When i set the date format, then it works. It display only date. But if i want to select time as well, then i can't select the time.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking is [`kendoDatePicker`](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/index),  which will allows user to select only date.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
     $("#txtDate").kendoDatePicker();
});
```

Edit: or add formatting property to `kendoDateTimePicker`, which will effect how value is displayed for user.

```
$('#txtDate').kendoDateTimePicker({ 
    value: new Date(),
    format: 'MM/dd/yyyy'
});
```

Comment: It works. But if i want to select the time as well. Then i can't.

Comment: @CodeRider Well if you use `kendoDateTimePicker`, you can choose time

Comment: If i use the "format: 'MM/dd/yyyy'" then i'm not able to choose time.

Comment: it has parseFormats option, but for some reason it does not work with hours :/   http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datetimepicker#configuration-parseFormats

Answer (score 0):

If you **never** need to display the time one possible option might be to store the datetime value as an attribute of the current widget and on the submit event of the form manually ovverride the values:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#datetimepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
            format: "yyyy/MM/dd",
            change: function(data){
                data.sender.element.attr("value", data.sender.value());
            }
        });

    });

    $("form").on("submit", function(){
        $("input").each(function(){
            var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");

            if(inputValue){
                $(this).val(inputValue);
            }
        });

    })

</script>
```

If you want to display the time after the user pick a time you can change the format of the widget subscribing a function to the *open* event:

```
<input id="datetimepicker" />
<script>
$("#datetimepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
    format: "yyyy/MM/dd",
    value: new Date(),
    open: function(e){
        if(e.view == "time"){
        this.setOptions({format: "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"})
      }

      if(e.view == "date"){
        this.setOptions({format: "yyyy/MM/dd"})
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build on the answers given above and detect when a time is selected then reapply a display format in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Via jQuery:

```
$('#txtDate').datetimepicker({
        format: 'L'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Kendo.DateTimePickerFor you can use DatePickerFor.
This way you can get rid of hour part.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.StartDate).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control" , required="required"}))
```

[image]